Question put on hold as self help question when it isn't - how to improve?
I asked a question which has nothing to do with self help. It was about trying to find medical evidence to corroborate what was told to me by doctor.
Basically I was told that long psychiatric conditions (in this case schizophrenia) resulted in the brain suffering damage due to various reasons but these reasons were not laid out in any detail. I want to know what the clinical evidence is behind these claims and if there is any clinical evidence what parts of the brain are effected.
Here is the question:
Brain damage / change in long term psychiatric conditions such as schizophrenia
As you can see it clearly isn't a self help question. I added the information about my own condition as a bit of background to the question. The real meat of the question is the last paragraph which spells out what I wanted:
"Being a person who enjoys knowing the facts behind any claims made can anyone provide clinical proof to what my psychiatrist is saying? I have found many academic papers both agreeing with and disagreeing with the statement but finding an agreed upon consensus is difficult. I'm also looking for evidence indicating what effect a schizophrenic relapse has on the brain and the exact degenerative effects that occur."

The original question could definitely be seen as self-help. What's edit fixed that, so I reopened.
